# How to get an optional argument through generic type in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function like this in typescript:

```
function foo<P>(param: P) {
  // ...
}
```

I want when provide generic type `P`, then `param` should be required

```
foo<string>('bar')
```

And when not provide generic type `P`, then `param` should not be required

```
foo()
```

But in typescript, when calling `foo()`, ts will throw error: `[ts] Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.`

If I make `param` optional like this `function foo<P>(param?: P) {}`, then it will not throw error when calling `foo<string>()` while it should.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
function foo(): void;
function foo<P>(param: P): void;
function foo(param?: any) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer is right.  Actually, in my real case, the `foo` function pass the generic type to a new class like this `foo<P>() { return new Bar<P>()  }`, but class can't overload.

Comment: Ok, I solve it by use function overload, and define two class, one with generic type, and another without.  Thanks!